# When the match is getting tied then why some of matches remains tie, and some goes to Super Over?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc, cricket-world-cup

I saw so many matches when they tied, and result also comes by some very interesting plays, like Super Over, and some of the matches remains tie only. But in First T-20 World cup, when India and Pakistan's scores were level, then both the sides threw some deliveries to the stumps, what kind of rule was that?

Answer (score 3):

The first Twenty 20 world cup was played in the year of [2007](http://www.sportsaustralia.com/articles/news.php?id=1310) but, the super over was introduced by ICC only in the year of [2008](http://www.espncricinfo.com/stanfordtwenty20/content/story/375503.html).

When India and Pakistan's match went for tie in the first T20 world cup, [Bowl-Out method was used](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/6993851.stm) to break the tie. Then, the super-over method was [introduced to replace bowl-out](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/358299.html) method in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your main question:

> Why some of matches remains tie and some goes to superover?

The decision of keeping the match tie or go for tie breaker like Super Over depends on a particular series. Mostly, tie breaker is used in the series between more than two countries like any ICC world events, continent tournaments like Asia cup etc.

Regarding your other question (which is already answered by @Sports Fan):

The decision of which type of tie breaker (Bowl out or Super over etc.) should be taken also depends on the series.

---

**Edit: (As suggested by @Sports Fan)**

ICC announce such playing conditions before the tournament is started. See [this report in thehindu.com](http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/champions-trophy/super-over-to-decide-a-tie/article4827686.ece).

Comment: Nice answer, but a reference is better for that choice between Bowl-out and Super-over.

Comment: @SportsFan - As already mentioned, such rules are defined before the tournament start and this is not documented anywhere. Note: Mostly, tournament specific rules are not listed as it changes in every tournaments.

Comment: +1, I agree [ICC playing conditions](http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/champions-trophy/super-over-to-decide-a-tie/article4827686.ece) will be announced before tournament getting started. I'm not sure about the bilateral series.

Comment: @SportsFan - Thank you for your reference of a report. I forgot the word "playing condition". Editing in my answer. Thanks again.